# install package lda and pyprind

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, lda

I use Python 3 on Jupyter from Anaconda 2.3.0.
   I have installed LDA (Latent Dirichlet Analysis) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lda#downloads and 
   pyprind using `pip install lda` and `pip install pyprind`. 
   Seems installation is succesful, but when I tried `import lda` and `improt pyprind` in Jupyter, it shows error messages

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-1-f083730c43c2> in <module>()
   ----> 1 import lda
   ImportError: No module named 'lda'
```

or

```
   ...
   ImportError: No module named 'pyprind'
```

I roughly understand this is because the packages are not really successfully installed in Anaconda. Usually when I need some packages, I do `conda install xxxx`, not just `pip install xxx`. I even tried to type
`python` in the terminal, but still failed to import the libraries.

What if Anaconda hasn't supported the packages yet? Is there any way we can make sure when using Jupyter, we can import the packages. Should I uninstall anaconda?

Comment: Try `pip install PyPrind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

> conda install -c conda-forge pyprind